# Visual studio /editandcontinue error NEN1014 How can I resolve this error?

Tags: debugging, compiler-errors, c++17, visual-studio-2022, edit-and-continue

I'm trying to use the "Edit and Continue" feature in Visual Studio 2022, but it gives the warning "Code not able to compile" and then the following error:

`'Debug.exe' in 'Base.cpp' was not linked with Edit and Continue enabled. Make sure that the Edit and Continue option (/EDITANDCONTINUE) is not ignored by the connector in the Error List window.`

On the error screen, however, I did not see a warning that disables the /editandcontinue setting. I think I'm missing something in "Configuration Settings" but I couldn't find it. Also, the /ZI setting of the project and .cpp file is enabled.

I would be very grateful if you could help me solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [MS document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-edit-and-continue-in-visual-studio-2015-update-3/), it mentions

> Any incompatible compiler or linker settings will cause an error during Edit and Continue (for example, “’file.cpp’ in ‘MyApp.dll’ was not linked with Edit and Continue enabled. Ensure that /INCREMENTAL linking is enabled, and the /EDITANDCONTINUE directive is not ignored.”) ```.It indicates that your compiler's command options are not compatible.

Here’re suggestions you can check:

1 please check `Requirements for C++ Edit and Continue` and make sure you meet those settings.
For example, Edit and Continue isn't really compatible with /Gm-, it requires "Enable Minimal Rebuild" (/Gm). You can refer above doc to check one by one.

2 check  `Incompatible settings and unsupported scenarios`.

3 enable logging when running into issues with EnC. And it helps diagnose EnC issues.
From a Developer command prompt, run VsRegEdit.exe set “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio[Version][YOUR EDITION]” HKCU Debugger NativeEncDiagnosticLoggingLevel DWORD 1

4 reset all environment settings to one of default collections of setting
Tools->import and export settings->reset all settings.

BTW you can  look at your Compiler command line and Linker command line (path: right click project->select properties) and provide it so that we can help you check.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I checked all the settings on your comment but everything was the same. Then (for a long time) I was getting a warning about libjpeg and cryptlib. I compiled these two again in "appropriate settings" and added them to the project. And problem solved :)